# Setting stage to allow for any stage width or height

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder, mxml

I am developing a web application for a web firm, it is an "engine" that loads external swf files and presents them in a slideshow fashion much like what is presented a lot these days for website frontend header content areas

The thing is almost ready but I've hit a bit of a design roadblock. While i've been developing happily along with a stage width and height of 930x270, the truth is that not every single site is going to be using those dimensions. Everything that runs uses the stage.stageWidth property (and same with stage.stageHeight) for this exact reason, however I cannot seem to dynamically set the width and height values, even with basic to advanced embedding techniques on the web pages themselves.

Using the Flex/FlashBuilder meta info

```
[SWF(frameRate=30, widthPercent=100, heightPercent=100)]
```

or even if i set a specific width and height or not.
For example, if I dont set anything (just the framerate) and I embed the resulting swf on a page in an element thats 980x300, stage.stageWidth STILL reports back only 500, totally messing with how my elements are getting displayed.

I tried setting the scaleMode too, right now its set to

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;
```

its the first thing set in my constructor.Still 500 (without any meta information set, or even with widthPercent and heightPercent).

I need the ability for the embedded flash to be almost any size without the requirement of recompiling, No need to worry about aspect ratio either, the loaded content will be manually created for that particular project, but the entire project relies on the width property of the engines stage.

Sorry for the long wall of text, but I'm running out of ideas here...

Is there anything in MXML or some property I can modify or some embed tactic that I'm missing to get the stages properties set to the width and height of its embedded object?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding. "Everything that runs uses stage.stageWidth property for this exact reason" What is "everything" in this case?  What is the reason it is used? How are you trying to dynamically set the stageWidth/stageHeight?  In Flex you wouldn't normally touch the stage directly.

Comment: Its a "loader engine" project, its designed for one thing and one thing only: loading swf files into it (referenced from an XML file), playing each one (one by one) and when the active swf file is done playing it shifts each swf to the left by the amount of the entire stagewidth (so they can be reset back to frame 1 off screen and the new active swf can begin playing).

When the stage.stageWidth only reports 500, then that means each swf is only being offset by 500, and they are only shifting left or right by increments of 500

Comment: So when in an embed tag or swfObject element the width and height is set to something like 930x270, and the engine still only reports back a 500px width from there, everything (in that case) begins getting overlapped, you see

Comment: I think setting stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE would be better in a case like this (EXACT_FIT will stretch the swf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the following:

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

Also use a method outside of the main constructor to get the stageHeight and stageWidth sometimes the stage is not 'ready' yet.

Comment: Ah Perfect! Works like a charm! Thanks! :D Just gotta adjust some math now :D (I KNEW there'd be a way, just wasn't hitting it right)